# Issues with RazorLight Layout in .net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razorengine, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I am having issues with Razor Light `CompileRenderAsync` in .net core 3.1. I have a view `test.cshtml` which has `Layout` property defined as below but when I see the output of the `CompileRenderAsync` Layout view is not getting appended. It used to work fine in .net core 2.1 version after the upgrade I am facing these issues. Any idea is this a known bug? As an alternative is there a way to fix this issue in .net core 3.1?

`@using RazorLight
@{
    Layout = "Templates.MainLayout";
}`

Comment: Honestly, if I were you, I would choose another library than `RazorLight`. The maintainer is closing issues on GitHub even though issues aren't actually fixed. 
I've used in it in the past in a previous job and I regretted it. This project should be avoided in my opinion

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL Any proper alternatives?

Comment: @Javid sorry I haven't used any other alternatives.  I didn't have to use such library again at my job...

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue and for me it was related to the use of partial views. There's a bug in the library. There's a PR that's been waiting for merge conflicts to be resolved for 2 months to fix this, so I've raised another one with them resolved.
https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight/issues/287

With any luck, 2.0.0.beta5 will contain the fix.

Comment: the Issue is resolved in the latest release. Try to upgrade with the latest release which should work as expected.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I forgot to post an update here. I merged the fix in and they kindly did a beta release immediately. https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight/pull/329